# Looking for a way to filter data withing Azure API call

Tags: json, azure, api, filter

I am looking for a way to extract data out of an azure environment. Problem i'm currently having is that when I use my API call I receive about 60 lines of json while I only need 4 of those lines. To reduce load, increase efficiency and remove the need for parsing withing the other environment where I need to data, I want to find a way to filter the data in the api call. Currently my call looks like this.

[https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription}/resourceGroups/{resourcegroup}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{application](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7Bsubscription%7D/resourceGroups/%7Bresourcegroup%7D/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/%7Bapplication) or resource}/providers/microsoft.insights/metrics?api-version=2021-05-01&metricnames=IoWriteBytesPerSecond,IoReadBytesPerSecond&timeSpan=PT1M

now the ouput looks something like this.

```json
{
    "cost": 0,
    "timespan": "2022-10-11T10:18:00Z/2022-10-11T10:19:00Z",
    "interval": "PT1M",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "/subscriptions//resourceGroups//providers/Microsoft.Web/sites//providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics/IoWriteBytesPerSecond",
            "type": "Microsoft.Insights/metrics",
            "name": {
                "value": "IoWriteBytesPerSecond",
                "localizedValue": "IO Write Bytes Per Second"
            },
            "displayDescription": "The rate at which the app process is writing bytes to I/O operations. For WebApps and FunctionApps.",
            "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
            "timeseries": [
                {
                    "metadatavalues": [],
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "timeStamp": "2022-10-11T10:18:00Z",
                            "total": 288.0
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "errorCode": "Success"
        },
        {
            "id": "/subscriptions//resourceGroups//providers/Microsoft.Web/sites//providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics/IoReadBytesPerSecond",
            "type": "Microsoft.Insights/metrics",
            "name": {
                "value": "IoReadBytesPerSecond",
                "localizedValue": "IO Read Bytes Per Second"
            },
            "displayDescription": "The rate at which the app process is reading bytes from I/O operations. For WebApps and FunctionApps.",
            "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
            "timeseries": [
                {
                    "metadatavalues": [],
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "timeStamp": "2022-10-11T10:18:00Z",
                            "total": 284.0
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "errorCode": "Success"
        }
    ],
    "namespace": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
    "resourceregion": "westeurope"
}
```

Out of all these lines I only need about 4 objects, Is it possible to use the $filter function within the URL api call? If yes, can someone redirect me to a forum, doc or example where this is used?

Thanks, regards

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this isn't supported for any ARM APIs. Feel free to raise a feature request for the same [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community).